# Taylor expansion of a non smooth function

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Is there a Taylor expansion for the following function:

$ f(x) = \begin{cases}x  & \mbox{if }x \ge 0, \\ 0 &\text{if }x < 0\end{cases} $

I know that at x = 0 the function is not smooth but at every other point it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are Taylor expansions for this function, centred at $x = a$, so long as $a \neq 0$.

If $a > 0$, then $f(x) = x$ locally around $x = a$, so the Taylor series is simply the Taylor series for the function $x$ at $x = a$, i.e.
$$a + (x - a) + 0(x - a)^2 + 0(x - a)^3 + \ldots$$

Similarly, if $a < 0$, then $f(x) = 0$ locally around $x = a$, so the Taylor series is the zero series:
$$0 + 0(x - a) + 0(x - a)^2 + \ldots$$

It's worth noting that, in this case, the radius of convergence of these series are infinite, although the series don't converge to the function $f$ past the point $a$. That is, the Taylor series don't provide an approximation of the function for certain points far away from the centre, even though the series converge to a finite value at these points.