# Approximating expansion for non-smooth or nonlinear functions?

Tags: taylor-expansion, approximation, neural-networks, nonlinear-analysis, non-smooth-analysis

Are there some examples or research trends to find approximating expansions to nonlinear or non-smooth functions that have some nice properties from the Taylor expansion - e.g. possibility to use some first terms only to achieve good approximation.

I have read previous question [Taylor expansion of a non smooth function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4080237/taylor-expansion-of-a-non-smooth-function) but it is very narrow in scope and the answer is similarly narrow. There is some hint that there may be factional Taylor expansions for that https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0898122106000861 ("Modified Riemann-Liouville derivative and fractional Taylor series of nondifferentiable functions further results") but is it general theory for nonlinear approximation and the state-of-the-art?

I am trying to think about approximating ReLU neural function from the deep learning theory in the style of https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.10165 but I need some guidance what tools can be applied for that. The mentioned book stops exactly at the same question.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how much help this is as an answer, but I recently had the same or similar question and found a math paper that ostensibly works towards this: [Piecewise Polynomial Taylor Expansions—The Generalization of Faà di Bruno’s Formula](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-030-55240-4_3).

It appears to generalize Taylor's theorem and series, normally used for smooth functions, to use with non-smooth functions. They do so with the help of Faà di Bruno’s Formula. There are several similar papers by this research group. Hopefully this can point you in a good direction. My research background is more on the engineering side, and unfortunately I don't have much skill deciphering math papers or locating the practical stuff among the proofs and prepositions.